# Наголос у слові «Констант»

Tags: наголос, іншомовні-слова, from-latin

Ім'я римського імператора «Constans» (із наголосом на першому складі) у Вікіпедії та інших джерелах перекладено з латинської як «Констант». Наголос зберігається на першому складі («Кóнстант») чи переміщується на другий («Констáнт»)?